# External Binary Storage SP2010 large file SPFile.OpenBinaryStream() gives SQL server timeout

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have got large zip files (500MB to 5GB) which are processed with custom sharepoint job. When job is executed SPFile.OpenBinary() is fired and SQL Server timeout exception is logged into sharepoint web server logs. SQL server and sharepoint are on same machine. I am able to download and upload files using sharepoint web interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SPFile.OpenBinaryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470901.aspx) instead.

It's a **very bad idea** to read a multi-gigabyte file into a single `byte[]` which is exactly what `SPFile.OpenBinary` does. Also, you should consider two things when dealing with such large amounts of data in SharePoint:

- rethink your IT infrastructure and *at least* make SQL Server run on its own machine;
- consider using [RBS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474.aspx) to offload document BLOBs out of SharePoint (this is definitely not just a matter of configuration, proper licensing and 3rd party products are a must for production environments).

Comment: of course we use OpenBinaryStream, sorry for my mistake. We excluded big files from sharepoint and processing in other way.